# Cordova iOS strange behavior, app close after splashscreen

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I have experienced a strange behavior on a demo app i've done.

I'm learning how to develop apps with cordova, i developed a really simple demo app and i installed it with "RUN" of the xcode, in my iPhone 5S with iOS 9.3.

At first the app works really well but after a few days the app starts closing/crashing after the splashscreen.

The app stays in background but when i try to bring it up it closes/crashes again.

-- UPDATE --
After using Configurator for logging i got this :

==========  15/07/2016, 15:31:57  ==========

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis SpringBoard[54] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis SpringBoard[54] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis securityd[93] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis securityd[93] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis amfid[2207] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis amfid[2207] : MIS: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'iOS Team Provisioning Profile: io.ionic.luis.conference'

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis amfid[2207] : /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE241426-5F1E-43B1-911F-C1C292F57F9D/RederiaCatalog.app/RederiaCatalog not valid: 0xe8008016: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.project.rederia[0xfc77][2872]) : Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis assertiond[63] : Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 2872: (os/kern) failure (5)

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis SpringBoard[54] : Unable to register for exec notifications: No such process

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis SpringBoard[54] : Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 2872: (os/kern) failure (5)

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis SpringBoard[54] : Unable to obtain a task name port right for 

Jul 15 15:32:00 iPhone-de-Luis SpringBoard[54] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.project.rederia[0xfc77]' exited abnormally via signal.

Jul 15 15:32:01 iPhone-de-Luis SpringBoard[54] : Application '(null)' exited for an unknown reason.

Comment: You need to provide some code or error messages in order to get more adequat help.

Comment: The problem is that i dont have any errors, the app works fine but then after a few days stops openings and i cant find any logs on iPhone.

Comment: What can i do to debug, because if i run the app in xcode it works fine again.

Comment: connect the device to apple configurator and try to get the logs.

Comment: I got the log, i edited the post.